# Neo4j Browser relationship limit?

Tags: neo4j

Neo seems to returning an incorrect value from an aggregate on a large number of relationships. **Note: I'm using the Neo browser for all my queries.**

I start by creating some simple sample data:

```
CREATE (p:PERSON)
CREATE (e:EVENT)
WITH range(0, 100000) AS list, p, e
UNWIND list AS val  
CREATE (p)-[:ATTENDED {val: val}]->(e)
```

And then run my aggregate:

```
MATCH (:PERSON)-[a:ATTENDED]->(:EVENT)
RETURN avg(a.val)
```

I get the value 7050.7... instead of 50000 as expected. I ran `count`, `min` and `max` aggregates as well and they are all as expected (100001, 0, 100000 respectively).

Is there something wrong with my code? or is there some sort of limitation in the Neo browser? or something else...?

#### Note:

If I run the same queries but only create the range to 10000:

```
...
WITH range(0, 10000) AS list, p, e
...
```

I get the expected value from the aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the result of unsigned 32-bit [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

If you altered your query to return the sum, you would also have seen a wrong result:

```
MATCH (:PERSON)-[a:ATTENDED]->(:EVENT)
RETURN SUM(a.val);
```

Instead of `5000050000` (the result of `50000*100001`), the returned sum would be approximately `705082704` (the actual sum depends on what value(s) caused the overflow(s) to occur).

The largest unsigned 32-bit integer value is `4294967295` (or 2^32 - 1). If you add that to `705082704`, or whatever your sum is, you get a total that is close to the expected `5000050000`. It would generally not be exactly the expected value, because the overflow generally occurs "in the middle of" adding a number and not "at the beginning".

If your query converted the values to floating point, you would have seen the expected results:

```
MATCH (:PERSON)-[a:ATTENDED]->(:EVENT)
RETURN AVG(TOFLOAT(a.val))
```

Alternatively, if you had stored floating point property values, your original query would have worked:

```
CREATE (p:PERSON)
CREATE (e:EVENT)
WITH RANGE(0, 100000) AS list, p, e
UNWIND list AS val  
CREATE (p)-[:ATTENDED {val: TOFLOAT(val)}]->(e);
```

Comment: Ahh... Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Avg and sum had an bug where they integer-overflowed, for avg it was solved here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/5707

You can reproduce your issue quickly with:

```
UNWIND range(0, 100000) as x
return min(x),max(x),count(x),sum(x),avg(x),sum(x) / count(x)
```

and cybersam's suggestion with:

```
UNWIND range(0, 100000) as x
with toFloat(x) as x
return min(x),max(x),count(x),sum(x),avg(x),sum(x) / count(x)
```